# failed to load resource the network connection was lost with safari 9 & jboss wildfly 8.2

Tags: javascript, jboss, safari, wildfly-8, safari-web-inspector

i have deployed My War file to jboss wildfly 8.2 server and trying to use app link on remote MAC Machine.

application open correctly but some functionality didn't works and give Error on Safari Web Inspector Console as follows:-

```
"Failed to load a resource: The network connection was lost."
```

its trying to load a JS file.

when i go to Resources tab & open this JS file its open in browser mean its included correctly but safari didnt load it proper way.

i find some ideas about `Transfer-Encoding`  & etc. but i don't know how to resolve this issue.

Please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a solution.

with WildFly 8.2.0 it's not working but its working fine with WildFly 8.2.1
so maybe there is some changes or bug.